# Why Jenkins does not run a job as scheduled?

Tags: jenkins, delay, server

I have this 'Build periodically' option with the following 'Schedule':

```
H 6,13 * * *
```

Meaning that I want this job to be run everyday at 6:00 and 13:00.

I noticed that it does not run at the specified time but 34 minutes later instead. These are the last builts:

```
#3​06 12-feb-2015 6:34
#3​05 11-feb-2015 13:34
#3​04 11-feb-2015 6:34
#3​03 10-feb-2015 13:34
#3​02 10-feb-2015 6:34
```

Plus, under the 'Schedule' text area there is a note saying:

```
Would last have run at Thursday, February 12, 2015 6:34:42 AM CET;
would next run at Thursday, February 12, 2015 1:34:42 PM CET.
```

This is not a big deal, but it is a bit annoying that there is a 34 minutes delay. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it (without manually adding this delay on the schedule)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the H by 0 to have 6:00.

The H is intended to distribute tasks over the hour, so not all Jenkins tasks start exactly at 06:00 etc. (so it is not a delay, but a different way of scheduling).

Two different tasks scheduled both at H 13 * * * will start at different minutes but still between 13:00 and 13:59:59, so they won't make your system too slow. The H value is the job specific hash value, so it will still be a constant within the job, but different between jobs.

Comment: What will you do now? Use the distributed version, or the version that starts at :00? (Of course that depends on the task)

Comment: For this job it doesn't really matter, but I'll take the version that starts at :00.